# Convert float to integer to get number without dot and zero

Tags: python

Can any one please to tell me how to round float to integer ?  I tried with np.round() on pred_y, I get dot zero like 12.0 for example and not 12 without dot zero, in python

Thank you for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with `numpy` array you can do the following

```
y = np.array(np.round(x), dtype=int)
```

However if its just a number `int(round(x))` will do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works well with : y = np.array(np.round(x), dtype=int)

Answer (score 0):

Use [int()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/int), Like this:

```
>>int(2.4)
2
>>int(4.0)
4
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

for convert float to int you just have to use int() function.

Example:

```
Int(128.2)
128
```

Comment: Thank you very much